# is this an android splash screen?

Tags: android, splash-screen

Hi I'm new to android and wondered if this is just something Google hashed together or if its built in for anyone to use, I'm refering to the (new?) splash screens they seem less of a splash screen and more a welcome activity that just shows how the app can and should be used its included in such programs as maps and drive and dolphin browser I think uses something extremely similar its like a dialogue window that let's you skip through a couple slides and then ends never to be seen again, I've created similar things in my activity as transparent overlays is this how its done or is there some built in frame work?

Comment: there is no built in splash activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a built in framework.  There are some 3rd party libraries to make this easier (Roman Nurik's Wizard library comes to mind).

Bottom line, there is no framework supplied control to enable this functionality, and you will need to create it yourself (using custom Activities or Dialogs as you see fit).

https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/wizardpager is the Wizard Pager lib I was referring to, but there are lots of other ones in GitHub if you search.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard framework.

You can simply create an activity that shows a spashscreen. You can use AsyncTask to handle the work an notify the splash screen to progress to another activity.